# What is difference between 'Items in the Solution' and 'Items in the Feature'?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2010 while programming with visual studio 2010 it provide us screen like http://vishsharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/05/create-event-receiver-for-specific-list.html. I want to know what is difference between  'Items in the Solution' and 'Items in the Feature' ? When we should use them ?

Comment: http://manish-sharepoint.blogspot.in/2010/01/difference-between-solution-and-feature.html

Comment: The linked page uses neither of the phrases you've quoted.  Without context it's a bit hard to say what you're having trouble understanding.

Comment: see step no 6 in link provided by me. see image their

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items in solution are all sharepoint items that can be deployed in this project , but Items in the feature are Items that will be deployed when you deploy and activate this feature only ,feature is the single deployment unit in sharepoint , and you can have many features in single project.